# Resteasy can't find @GET method on subreasource

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I set up a root resource Foo like this:

```
@ApplicationPath ("/foo")
@Path ("/")
public class Foo extends Application {

  private static Map<String, Bar> map = new HashMap<> ();

  @GET
  public Collection<String> keys () {
    return map.keySet ();
  }

  @Path ("{key}")
  @PUT
  public void put (@PathParam ("key") String k, Bar v) {
    map.put (k, v);
  }

  @Path ("{key}")
  public Bar get (@PathParam ("key") String k) {
    return map.get (k);
  }
}
```

And my subresource Bar like this:

```
public class Bar {

  private @JsonProperty String bar;

  @GET
  public String bar () {
    return bar;
  }

  @Path ("bar")
  @PUT
  public void bar (String bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

Calling `GET` on `/foo` works fine and produces `[]`. After that calling `PUT` to `/foo/a` with body `{"bar":"hello"}` (Jackson does serialization) goes fine and produces `204` (no content) as expected. After that calling `GET` on `/foo` produces `["a"]` as expected. Calling `GET` on `/foo/a` however results in a `405` and an exception on the server "RESTEASY003650: No resource method found for GET". I can provide full stack trace if that matters. I'm using Wildfly as my application server, my example is pretty much a carbon copy of the figure on top of http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/JAX-RS_Resource_Locators_and_Sub_Resources.html what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're pointing to 1.0.1 guide.  Are you really using 1.0.1 or some other version?

Comment: I just googled this guide, I'm using wildfly 10.1 so whatever's included in that.